# Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am using Windows Server 2003 R2 and want to schedule a task using Task Scheduler but it gives the following error.
0x80090016: Keyset does not exist.
Both Task scheduler and Protected storage service are running. Kindly help me how to resolve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246183/en-us ?

Comment: my windows registry is disabled..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to :

- stop the protected storage service
- Double-click My Computer, and then click Folder Options on the Tools menu. On the View tab, click to select Show hidden files and folders, and then click OK.
- Delete all of the files in the "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18" folder.
- restart protected storage service
- try to exexute the task

Comment: Please take the time to mark this as an answer (click the green tick)